# Fastest way to accomplish a lookup in C# and how to deal with imprecision of double values?

Tags: c#, double, lookup, lookup-tables

I have an array of doubles (from a calculation) with 327,680 values. I need to translate those values into a color 8 bit per color image. I need to have a lookup table that holds the double values as an index with a byte[3] array for the RGB values to be used as the visual representation of that temperature value. I have up to 15 ms to do this, no more.

The best idea I have come up with is using a dictionary for the colors. Here is minimal, complete and verifiable code that I have used for testing:

```
//Create lookup table
Dictionary<int, byte[]> Lookup = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
{
    byte bValue = (byte)i;
    byte[] b = new byte[3] { bValue, bValue, bValue };
    Lookup.Add(i, b);
}

//Make proto temp readings
int[] temps = new int[640 * 512];
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 640 * 512; i++)
{
    temps[i] = r.Next(0, 255);
}

int size = 640 * 512 * 3;
byte[] imageValues = new byte[size];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (int item in temps)
    {
        byte[] pixel = new byte[3];
        if (Lookup.TryGetValue(item, out pixel))
        {
            imageValues[index] = pixel[0];
            imageValues[index + 1] = pixel[1];
            imageValues[index + 2] = pixel[2];
            index += 3;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

**First question:** When I run this I get times in the 10ms - 14ms range depending on if the lookup table has 1200 items or 256 items. Is there a way to speed this up?

**Second question:** My actual key values will be temperatures (double) that are the result of a calculation. For some reason doubles seem to have a little imprecision in the least significant digits. I have noticed that a result that should have turned out as 25 ends up being 25.00000000012 or something like that. If I am using doubles as the search value then I have the real risk of looking for 25 when the actual key value is 25.00000000012 or vice versa.

I can truncate or something when I am creating the doubles but I am worried about the time to do that.

What are some good strategies for dealing with the double imprecision issue when using the double as a key?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are doing with your doubles (your code doesn't show). Don't use doubles if you can avoid them; doubles are necessarily inexact. If you only have 328k possible values, encode whatever the double represents as an int or a short.

Comment: Is there a range that holds your doubles? What about expected precision?

Answer (score 3):

> First question: Is there a way to speed this up?

You have unneccesary memory allocation

```
byte[] pixel = new byte[3];
```

You can either leave the empty variable declaration

```
byte[] pixel;
```

or use inline variable declaration

```
if (Lookup.TryGetValue(item, out byte[] pixel))
```

This change improves performance in my tests.

Comment: Good tip. That took about a millisecond off the time.

Comment: Using ValueTuple instead of byte array is also speeding up about 25% on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve both problems by replacing the `Dictionary<T,byte[]>` with a `byte[][]`, and mapping each temperature `double` to an `int` index into the color array.

So take the range of temperatures, divide it into N equal partitions, where N is the number of elements in your color array. Take each measured temperature and map it to a partition number, which is also an array index into the colors.

The function to map a temperature to an array index would be something like:

```
temp => (int)(pixelValues * (temp - minTemp) / (maxTemp - minTemp));
```

EG

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp21
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double maxTemp = 255;
            double minTemp = -35;

            int pixelValues = 1200;
            byte[][] Lookup = new byte[pixelValues][];
            for (int i = 0; i < Lookup.Length; i++)
            {
                byte bValue = (byte)i;
                byte[] b = new byte[3] { bValue, bValue, bValue };
                Lookup[i] = b;
            }

            //Make proto temp readings
            double[] temps = new double[640 * 512];

            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 640 * 512; i++)
            {
                temps[i] =  r.NextDouble() * maxTemp;
            }

            int size = 640 * 512 * 3;
            byte[] imageValues = new byte[size];
            var timings = new List<long>(50);
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                sw.Start();
                int index = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < temps.Length; j++)
                {
                    var lookupVal = (int)(pixelValues * (temps[j] - minTemp) / (maxTemp - minTemp));
                    byte[] pixel = Lookup[lookupVal];
                    imageValues[index] = pixel[0];
                    imageValues[index + 1] = pixel[1];
                    imageValues[index + 2] = pixel[2];
                    index += 3;

                }
                sw.Stop();
                var ms = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                timings.Add(ms);
                //Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Max {timings.Max()} Avg {timings.Average()}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

outputs

> Max 7 Avg 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Like Ivan said move the memory allocation which will save you ~20%

You can save another 50% if you create a lookup array with all possible temperature values (just use the resolution of your sensor).

```
//Create array lookup table
List<byte[]> array = new List<byte[]>(25500);
for (int i = 0; i < 25500; i++)
{
    byte bValue = (byte)i;
    byte[] b = new byte[3] { bValue, bValue, bValue };
    array.Add(b);
}
```

This will give you temperatures from 0 to 255.00
Then you can access the desired value like so

```
int size = 640 * 512 * 3;
byte[] imageValues = new byte[size];

var sw = new Stopwatch();
byte[] pixel = new byte[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    sw.Start();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (var item in temps)
    {
        pixel = array[item * 100];
        imageValues[index] = pixel[0];
        imageValues[index + 1] = pixel[1];
        imageValues[index + 2] = pixel[2];
        index += 3;
     }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}/{sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 50.0}");
```

This will bring you below 5ms for a single lookup

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit unfair, as it optimizes your example and not your real problem, but perhaps can be applied. You know you are looking up `int`s, so just use a jagged array: `byte[][]`. This averages 0.66ms on my PC versus 5.4ms for your original.

Note: Using a `Dictionary<int,(byte,byte,byte)>` is about a 4ms with a `ValueTuple` holding the 3 `byte`s.

```
var repeats = 50;

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("byte[][3]");
//Create lookup table
var lookups = 1200;
var Lookup = new byte[lookups][];
for (int i = 0; i < lookups; i++) {
    byte bValue = (byte)i;
    var b = new byte[3] { bValue, bValue, bValue };
    Lookup[i] = b;
}


//Make proto temp readings
int[] temps = new int[640 * 512];
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 640 * 512; i++) {
    temps[i] = r.Next(0, 255);
}


int size = 640 * 512 * 3;
byte[] imageValues = new byte[size];

long totalMS = 0;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
    sw.Restart();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (int item in temps) {
        if (item < lookups) {
            var pixel = Lookup[item];
            imageValues[index] = pixel[0];
            imageValues[index + 1] = pixel[1];
            imageValues[index + 2] = pixel[2];
            index += 3;
        }
    }
    sw.Stop();
    totalMS += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    //Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

Console.WriteLine($"Average: {totalMS / (double)repeats} ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize more cores of your machine, assuming that it has more than one. Probably it is a good idea to not utilize all of them, and leave one free for the OS and other apps. The code below uses [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) with a range [partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner), and speeds up the execution from 21 msec to 8 msec in my machine.

```
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Math.Max(1, Environment.ProcessorCount - 1)
};
Parallel.ForEach(Partitioner.Create(0, temps.Length), options, range =>
{
    for (int item = range.Item1; item < range.Item2; item++)
    {
        byte[] pixel = new byte[3];
        if (Lookup.TryGetValue(item, out pixel))
        {
            int updatedIndex = Interlocked.Add(ref index, 3);
            int localIndex = updatedIndex - 3;
            imageValues[localIndex] = pixel[0];
            imageValues[localIndex + 1] = pixel[1];
            imageValues[localIndex + 2] = pixel[2];
            //index += 3;
        }
    }
});
```

I made no other changes to your code. I didn't optimize the unnecessary array allocation for example.

---

Btw multithreading creates issues with thread safety. For this reason I edited my answer to increment `index` using [`Interlocked.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add) instead of `+=`. Shared access to the `imageValues` array is probably safe.

Comment: Good idea! I'll look into that. I have avoided multi threading because it looks like it can be pretty complex. Using Parallel.ForEach actually looks pretty easy on the surface!

Comment: Yes, `Parallel.ForEach` is not that hard. You must be careful though with shared state. My example was buggy because I hadn't noticed that the shared `index` variable was used inside the loop as an indexer for the array. This would produce some pretty strange artifacts to the image! I made a correction by bypassing any direct access to the variable, introducing local variables (local for each thread). Ideally you should avoid situations like this. For example could you deduce the `index` by multiplying the loop variable `item` by 3?